# Autoit key remapping on Ubuntu (2nd day on Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, autoit

I am trying to remap alt-s to ctrl-s with autoit, but somehow it does not work. Can anybody give me a small hint?

```
# Enter script code
keyboard.press_key("<ctrl>")
keyboard.send_key("s")
keyboard.release_key("<ctrl>")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a script copied from the [AutoIt Fuction help site](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm). I just modified the line with the Alt+S HotKeySet and the function ShowMessage(). In future try to find the commands and interpret the examples. It's possible to learn AutoIt just with those documents.

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("!s", "ShowMessage") ; Shift-Alt-d

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func TogglePause()
    $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
    While $g_bPaused
        Sleep(100)
        ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
    WEnd
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc   ;==>TogglePause

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate

Func ShowMessage()
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}")
    Send("s")
    Send("{CTRLUP}")
EndFunc   ;==>ShowMessage
```

Short Version with no pause function:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("!s", "ShowMessage") ; Shift-Alt-d
While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate
Func ShowMessage()
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}")
    Send("s")
    Send("{CTRLUP}")
EndFunc   ;==>ShowMessage
```

Comment: Thx a lot, Ike. It does not work - 'script encounters an error', but I will research more with your suggestions and links.

Comment: I'm aware that this won't work if you just copy paste it, because this is pure AutoIt code. You need to modify it for your programming language and because of the lack of information i don't know how it should look like. This script works for me on a Win7 machine. I guess you're using an plugin for Python but I'm not sure. Maybe post your full code or more of it.

Comment: Thank you, Ike. No worries, I will figure this out. I always used Autohotkey and it works perfectly on Windows. I guess this is Linux issue but I will get it after research of the link you sent me. Have a nice weekend!